# IBM MobileFirst JSONStore is not getting initialized in 7.1 CLI Project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore, mobilefirst-cli

While trying to initialize JSONStore in IBM MobileFirst 7.1 CLI project that use 
the `cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore`, I am getting this error,

```
Uncaught Error: Failed to call WL.JSONStore.init because JSONStore is 
missing in the application. Add JSONStore to the application descriptor, 
rebuild and deploy it.
at Object.init (worklight.js:11414)
at JSONStoreHelper.initCollection (jsonstore-helper.js:30)
at JWTokenManager.initializeTokenStore (jwtoken-manager.js:26)
at wlCommonInit (index.js:20)
at Object.wlInit [as onSuccess] (worklight.js:8136)
at finalizeInit (worklight.js:7418)
at __WLClient.init (worklight.js:8471)
at HTMLScriptElement.mfpready (bootstrap.js:45)
```

MobileFirst CLI version is `7.1.0.00.20170421-0734`. Have anyone faced the same? Thanks.

Comment: The issue is not getting resolved though the '<features> <JSONStore/>   </features>' is added in applicationdescriptor.xml.

Comment: Just to be sure, instead of adding directly to application-descriptor.xml, can you try it from the CLI itself? Like so:
mfp add feature jsonstore

Comment: @VivinK Tried with the mfp add feature command now. Getting Error: Could not add MobileFirst feature.Error: You must be in a Hybrid app to execute this command. I am working on a project created using 'mfp cordova create' command

Comment: You should be within the created Cordova project to add it.